# What is the fastest way to calculate position cluster centers constriant by a concave polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a distribution of weighted 2D pose estimates (position + orientation) that are samples of an unknown PDF of a systems pose. All estimates and the underlying real position are constrained by a concave polygon.

[image]

The picture shows an exemplary distribution. The magenta colored circles are the estimates, the radius line indicates the estimated direction. The weights are indicated by the circles diameter. The red dot is the weighted mean, the yellow cirlce indicates the variance and the direction but is of no importance for the following problem:

From all estimates I want to derive the most likely position of the system.

Up to now I have evaluated the following approaches:

1. **Using the estimate with the highest weight**: Gives poor results since one estimate with a high weight outperforms several coinciding estimates with slightly lower weights.
2. **Weighted Mean**: Not applicable since the mean might lie outside the polygon as in the picture (red dot with yellow circle).
3. **Weighted Median**: Would work but does neglect potential clusters. E.g. in the image below two clusters are prominent of which one is more likely than the other.

Additionally I have looked into K-Means and K-Medoids. For K-Means I do not know the most efficient way to constrain the centers to the polygon. K-Medoids seems to work, but has poor performance (O(n^2)), which is important since I have a high number of estimates (contrary to explanatory picture)

- What would be the ideal algorithm to solve this kind of problem ?
- What complexity can be achieved ?
- Are there readily available algorithms in c++ that solve this problem, or can be easily adapted to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

k-means may also yield an estimate outside your polygons.
Such constraints are beyond the clustering use case. But nothing prevents you from devising a method to correct the estimates afterwards.

For non-convex data, DBSCAN may be worth a try. You could even incorporate line-of-sight into Generalized DBSCAN easily. But I'm not convinced that clustering will help for your overall objective.

Comment: That's what I fear as well, even if I constrain k-means like e.g. like in COP for example the "means" might still come to lie anywhere. You hint that you would not approach this problem with clustering. What would be your take on it?

Comment: I think the weighted mean, combined with geometric constaints, will work better.